# Minimizing the surface area of a rectangular prism with volume $50000$L.

Tags: calculus

> A town wants to build a water tank to hold 50000L of water. They want to minimize the amount of material used to build the tank by minimizing the surface area. If they make the water tank into a closed rectangular prism, what would the dimensions be?

Comment: A cube has the smallest surface:volume ratio, so the expected answer is $\sqrt[3]{50}m$.  Of course, to prove this, you can write the dimensions of the rectangular prism in terms of one variable and the volume, then use your typical optimization techniques to proceed.

Comment: It should be a cube.

Comment: And what did you do so far?

Comment: Is the tank open or closed?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! The community here prefers/expects questions to include something of what the asker knows about a problem. This information helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already know or talking over your head. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you.) Since comments are easily overlooked, please [edit your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3496654/edit) to include additional details.

Comment: [How To Ask A Homework Question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1803/265466).

Answer (score -1):

Volume of the cube is $50 kL$. Hence, $lbh=50000$. If the surface area is minimum, then $lb+2h(l+b)$ has to be minimized.
Using  $h=\frac{50000}{lb}$ we get $SA=lb+100000\frac{l+b}{lb}$.
By argument of symmetry, $l=b$.
Minimizing $l^2+\frac{200000}{l}$ gives $l=10\sqrt[3]{100}$ and $h=5\sqrt[3]{100}$

Comment: $50000L=50m^3$, no?  From where does your $lbh=50000$ come?

Comment: @AndrewChin I have not written $m^3$ or used $m$ anywhere. Unit conversion can be easily done. My focus was on the answer.

Answer (score -2):

A cube, $a=\sqrt[3]{50}\approx3.68 m=368 cm$, $A=6a^²≈81.22 m^²$
If a shape of water tank is arbitrary, then it's a sphere , $R=\sqrt[3]{\frac{3*50}{4\pi})}\approx2.28 m, A_1=4\pi R^2\approx 65.52 m^2$

Comment: A cube has minimum area:volume ration if it is closed. A tank is however, generally assumed to be open at the top.

Comment: Definitely, generally assumed to be closed tank, though there must be a clarification.

Comment: Yeah I realized that so I added if it was closed or not :) thank you for reminding me

Comment: If tank is open, let a,b,c are prism sides. Volume of a prism is V=abc. Then, A=ab+2ac+2bc. Use Cauchy inequality:ab+2ac+2bc ≥3³√(ab*2ac*2bc)=3³√(4*V²). Minimum accomplished if :ab=2ac & ab=2bc. Hence, a=b=2c, 4c³=V, c=³√(2V)/2≈2.317 
  a=b=³√(2V)=³√100≈4.634